# Running native server with webview

Tags: android, webview

I've a binary file that is running as a server at android port `http://localhost:8090/hello`.
Once I run this `server` binart from `Termux` I was able to see the output smoothly at chrome with the menthioned url.

I'm trying to bundle this binary with the APK and run it from the Anroid app, and display the output using `webview`, so:

1. I added the file to the `assets` folder
2. Trying to copy the file from the `assets` to the apk folder
3. Trying making the copyied file executable
4. trying to execute the copied file
5. Trying to load the output at the webview

My code is:

```kotlin
package com.example.app101

import android.R.attr.path
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.AssetManager
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.WebResourceError
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import android.widget.Toast
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream

class MainActivity : Activity() {  // AppCompatActivity()
     //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/yourapp/"
    private lateinit var myWebView: WebView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       // val context = applicationContext

        copyFile(this.applicationContext)
        // /data/data/app-package-name   /data/data/com.example.app101

        (findViewById<View>(R.id.webview)  as WebView).also { myWebView = it }
        val path: String = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/index.html").toString()
        myWebView.apply {
            // Configure related browser settings
            scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
            // Configure the client to use when opening URLs
         //   webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                }

                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                   // Toast.makeText(context, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onReceivedError(
                        view: WebView?,
                        request: WebResourceRequest?,
                        error: WebResourceError?
                ) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error $error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onPageCommitVisible(
                        view: WebView,
                        url: String
                ) {
                    super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
                }
            }.also { webViewClient = it }
            settings.apply {
                loadsImagesAutomatically = true
                javaScriptEnabled = true
                // Enable responsive layout
                useWideViewPort = true;
                // Zoom out if the content width is greater than the width of the viewport
                loadWithOverviewMode = true;
                // Load the initial URL
                supportZoom()
                builtInZoomControls = true // allow pinch to zooom
                displayZoomControls = false // disable the default zoom controls on the page

            }

            //loadUrl(path)
            // loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8090/hello")  // load localhost imulater
            loadUrl("http://localhost:8090/hello")  // load localhost device
        }
    }
}

private fun copyFile(context: Context) {
    val path= "/Android/data/com.example.app101"
    val assetManager: AssetManager = context.assets
    try {
        val `in`: InputStream = assetManager.open("server")
        val out: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(path)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var read: Int = `in`.read(buffer)
        while (read != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read)
            read = `in`.read(buffer)
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod +x server")
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path + "server")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message
    }
}
```

But unfortunatly I can not see that the file had been copies, as well as I did not see anything at the webvie except the error shown.

[image]

Comment: You should probably start by checking the output streams to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Kyle How can I do that?

Comment: exec returns a Process. use getErrorStream and getOutputStream. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process#getErrorStream()